# How can I create those nested objects

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have two models User and Vendor(they are linked with a oneToOne, i want to create a Vendor which includes a new User.

Problem, when i use the method User.objects.create(UserSerializer(),validated_data=user_data) inside my override method create() of VendorSerializer, i get a "create() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given" error

what can i do more than override create in the UserSerializer() ? already tried

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'username'
        )

class VendorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Vendor
        fields = ('user','no_rue','adresse','code_postal','ville','pays')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user_data = validated_data.pop('user')
        user = User.objects.create(UserSerializer(),validated_data=user_data)
        vendor, created = Vendor.objects.update_or_create(user=validated_data.pop('user'),no_rue=validated_data.pop('no_rue'),
        adresse = validated_data.pop('adresse'),
        code_postal = validated_data.pop('code_postal'),
        ville = validated_data.pop('ville'),
        pays = validated_data.pop('pays'))
        return vendor




class Vendor(models.Model):
    rating = models.FloatField(
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        validators=[MaxValueValidator(5),MinValueValidator(1)]
    )
    IBAN = IBANField(null=True,unique=True, default=None)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    photo = models.ImageField(blank=True,null=True, upload_to='images') #Param: upload_to='directory'
    no_rue = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    adresse = models.CharField(max_length = 25)
    code_postal = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(99999),MinValueValidator(1000)])
    ville = modelenter code heres.CharField(max_length = 25)
    pays = models.CharField(max_length = 25)
    def __str__(self):
        if(self.user.first_name == ""):
            return self.user.username
        else:
            return self.user.first_name
```

Comment: try change to `User.objects.create(*user_data)`.

Comment: yes i forgot to close the subject, it was exactly this... (**user_data)